# How can i call functions on Golang?

Tags: function, go, if-statement, variables, output

I started coding a few days ago and I don't know how to call functions for a small project that I create now. It's a simple question but I'm struggling a lot. I will leave my code below, thank you!

```
package main

import "fmt"

func law(grade int) (mathews, john int) {
    mathews = 65
    john = 69
    grade = 70
    return
}

func main() {
    law()
    if mathews < grade {
        fmt.Println("Mathews, you are not allow to join on Harvard.")

    } else {
        fmt.Println("Congratulations, Mathews. You passed!")
    }
    if john < grade {
        fmt.Println("John, you are not allow to join on Harvard.")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Congratulations, John. You passed!")
    }
}
```

Comment: The [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org) is a good starting point for the basics

Comment: its much faster to invest time into learning a programming language by reading its docs + tutorials than to simply throw up the hands, post a question and wait ... key skill of any successful person is independence and fortitude ... struggle is good

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issue:

1. Your function `law` has an argument `grade` but you are not providing that argument when you are calling the function.
2. When you call the function you need to store whatever is returned by the function in a variable.

Try something like this

```
package main

import "fmt"

func law(grade int) (mathews, john int) {
    mathews = 65
    john = 69
    grade = 70 // This line is not doing anything so you should actually remove it.
    return
}

func main() {
    grade := 70
    mathews, john := law(grade)
    if mathews < grade {
        fmt.Println("Mathews, you are not allow to join on Harvard.")

    } else {
        fmt.Println("Congratulations, Mathews. You passed!")
    }
    if john < grade {
        fmt.Println("John, you are not allow to join on Harvard.")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Congratulations, John. You passed!")
    }
}
```

Checkout functions in `A Tour of Go`: https://tour.golang.org/basics/4 for a basic run through on how to use functions in Go.

Comment: I don't figure out yet :\